# Email: universal quoted text delimiter

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, html-email

I need to form a reply to an email that will have users input + some delimiter + body of the message the user is replying to.
What I can't seem to figure out is a way to separate the user message from the quoted text so that most mail clients would pick it up as a valid delimiter.

Something like this:

BAR
----Original Message----
FOO.

Answer (score 2):

Replies are typically prefixed with ">", for example:

```
BAR

Joe Foo wrote on <date>:
> FOO
> More FOO
```

A forwarded message is included as you suggest above, for example:

```
BAR

-------- Forwarded Message --------
Subject: whatever
Date: <date>
From: Joe Foo

FOO
More FOO
```

There are no "standards" for any of this, so different mailers will behave differently, and you might need to experiment with the mailers you care about most to get the effect you want.